# Dynamic List javascript, can't add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I am trying to get content from a JSON-object and dynamically built a ordered list with it (nested with sub(sub)items) with JavaScript. For the front-end lay-out I am using JS 'CollapsibleList' (http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/collapsible-lists/). In order to get the lay-out rendered right; I need to add the right class to the list item. This went well for some of them but I can't solve how to add the 'collapsibleListClosed' class.

[Here you can see the list-item of the ul class added well but the collapsibleListClosed class wasn't added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0z0W.png)

I guess the sub-sub items also will give some problems with this approach.

The code I used is:

```
list = $("<ul class='treeView2' id='productTree'>"); 
  for (var i = 0, l = jsonobject.length; i < l; ++i) {
list.append("<li><input type='text' value='" + jsonobject[i].id + "'</input><ul class='collapsibleList'><li class='collapsibleListClosed'>Test");  
                                               }
                                               $("#goo").append(list);
                                   })
                        });
```

The end-goal is that I for example have some Main items, subitems, sub- subitems and it automatically/dynamically generates the correct lists in the right structure

How can this be fixed please? Thank you!

Comment: This is my current progress: http://imgur.com/8pVJsLT and the result I want to become: http://imgur.com/K128Txx .

Comment: `input` doesn't have a close tag in HTML, just: `<input />` or `<input>`

Comment: you are also missing a `>` at the end of your input. your input tag should look like `<input type='text' value='" + jsonobject[i].id + "'>`

Comment: `it automatically/dynamically generates the correct lists in the right structure` what structure? what have you tried?

Comment: Thank you for the answers/support! I used the given advise and got a little further but haven't found the solution yet. This is the current list.append code: list.append("<li><input type='text' value='" + jsonobject[i].id + "'> <ul class='collapsibleList'><li class='collapsibleListClosed'>test2</li></ul></li>");  It doesn't assign the collapsiblelistClosed class to the list items of the ul with collapsibleList class.

Comment: It seems I can add any class without any problems, except when I use the collapsibleListClosed class (the one I need), it doesn't assign that class, never seen this before.

Comment: What I would like to become is something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870589/creating-a-nested-list-with-an-object-array ; creating a nested list but from a (JSON-)array (for example: [{id: 1, name: "MainItem"}, {id: 2, name: "MainItem", name2: "SubItem"}, {id: 3, name: "MainItem", name2: "SubItem", name3: "SubSubItem, name4: "SubsubsubItem"}] ,.. . So depending on the data that is in the array list, It generates the right listing. Thank you!